# OpenCV camera preview colours are off?

Tags: android, opencv

I'm trying the sample apps that come with OpenCV-android-sdk, but the colours in the preview seem to be off substantially. Here's the original preview from the Camera app in the emulator (API 25):

[image]

But sample apps like [tutorial-1-camerpreview](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/android/tutorial-1-camerapreview), [color-blob-detection](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/android/color-blob-detection) and [15-puzzle](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/android/15-puzzle) give a strong blue tint:

[image]

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: I think bgr and rgb are switched

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV uses BGR format instead of RGB in its default. A small Matlab script prooves that simply RGB and BGR have been switched. You can see it at the cups, that are red in the original but blue in the "wrong" image.

Here is the matlab script for prooving my theory

```
rgb = imread('C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\uA5Q1.png')
bgr = cat(3,squeeze(rgb(:,:,3)),squeeze(rgb(:,:,2)),squeeze(rgb(:,:,1)))
figure;
imshowpair(rgb,bgr,'Montage')
```

[image]

left side shows the image posted by op, right side shows bgr after changing the order.

In the most cases you have the following function:

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    return inputFrame.rgba();
}
```

You can alter this function, so that it shows the correct order, to do so you can use the `cvtColor` function. Which would look like the following:

```
rgba = cvtColor(img,CV_RGBA2BGRA);
```

Where img is your input image.
The name might be misleading but it will work no mather if you are using `CV_BGRA2RGBA` or `CV_RGBA2RGBA` since it will only switch the first and the lattest matrix in both cases

Comment: But `onCameraFrame()` already returns `inputFrame.rgba()` in the [sample code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/android/color-blob-detection/src/org/opencv/samples/colorblobdetect/ColorBlobDetectionActivity.java#L173).

Comment: Yes, but just cause the name is like it does not mean that the intern representaton of the matrices are correct. Like shown, this is the error and what needs to be fixed. You can also try to change the function responsible for displaying your mat

Comment: it probably returns rgba, but opencv assumes bgr(a) during rendering and saving